# Вычитание из меньшего числа большего и вывод этого числа вместе со знаком "-"

Tags: masm, ассемблер

Может кто-нибудь по пунктам расписать, как мне осуществить вычитание из меньшего числа большего и вывести это число вместе со знаком "-" на экран?

Comment: В чем возникла проблема?

Comment: Мне надо вычислить значение: 0.5а - 1.5b
Я написал код, и если ввести, например, значения 10 и 2 соответственно, то получаю нужный результат - 2. А если ввести так, чтобы 0,5a<1.5b, то выводятся какие-то символы (например при значениях 10 и 20 результат - "G1".

Comment: Скорее всего, Ваш результат в дополнительном коде. А алгоритм вывода этого не понял.

Comment: Какой алгоритм вы не поняли? Или вы о чем?)

Comment: алгоритм -> ассемблерный код, который выводит результат. Показали бы код, может и прояснилось бы.

Comment: Вот мой код, посмотрите, пожалуйста?
http://pastebin.com/mHJ58Br9

Answer (score 2):

Разбираем с конца. Раз вывело `G1`, значит в регистрах ah al было `47h 31h, до сложения с`30h`там было`17h 01h`. До деления на 10 в регистре al было 231 (= E7h). В бинарном представлении это 0b11100111. Левый разряд -1 - значит там отрицательное число (Вы везде оперируете 8 битными числами), переводим с дополнительного кода - это`-25`. А это и есть ожидаемый результат ( 5 * 10 - 1.5 * 20).

Как исправить? Написать нормальный преобразователь, который учитывает отрицательные числа и то, что знаковый результат 8 битового регистра может быть больше 100.
Правильный способ - использовать стандартную функцию [sprintf](http://www.rsdn.ru/forum/asm/1525075.all) или аналоги, раз уж Вы используете masm.

Comment: А вы случайно не знаете какую-нибудь хорошую книжку по masm'у или статейки какие-нибудь?
Просто только начинаю, ни условий, ни циклов не знаю как написать)
Спасибо большое за помощь!

Comment: http://wasm.ru/wault/ и дальше по тексту.

Comment: Еще раз спасибо!)